Doxygen: font sizes and other attributes of pdf (via latex)
Is there a canonical way to control the font in Doxygen 1.10.0's latex-pdf output? I looked inside refman.tex and changed 0.90 to 1.10 in the line \usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet} which did increase the font size.
But I do not know if there are some other side-effects of the change of that scaling, or if there is a better way to control the size of font and other attributes of the pdf (margins, etc.).

At the moment I don't see a / there is no  better way to control the fontsize. I'm not aware of any side effect, but when present it shouldn't be and should be reported so the cause of the problem can be found. You could search in https://tex.stackexchange.com/ whether there are any possible side effects (or ask a general question there)
